# POST запрос retrofit

Tags: java, android, сервер, retrofit

Столкнулся с проблемой POST запроса, когда сервер посылает 1 строку:

Принимает:

{ 
        nameAnt:"...", 
        pass:"..." 
   }

А отвечает:

{"result":"NOT QUERY"}

Пытаюсь вывести, в лог ответ, но не получается. Вот мой код:

ConrollerPost.Java:

```
package dev.busboozted;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ControllerPost implements Callback<RegistrationResponse> {

static final String BASE_URL = "http://busboosted.000webhostapp.com/";

public void start(String login, String password) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    Api gerritAPI = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    RegistrationBody reg = new RegistrationBody(login, password);

    Call<RegistrationResponse> call = gerritAPI.getResult(reg);
    call.enqueue(this);


}


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call,                 
   Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
    RegistrationResponse res = response.body();
System.out.println(res.result);
System.out.println("sdasdasdsadsad");

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

}
}
```

Действие на нажатие кнопки:

```
View.OnClickListener oclLoginIp = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ControllerPost controllet = new ControllerPost();
            controllet.start("debil", "qwerty");

        }
    };
```

И интерфейс:

```
package dev.busboozted;

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

 public interface Api {

  @POST("entranceAnt.php")
 public Call<RegistrationResponse> getResult(@Body RegistrationBody reg);

}
```

RegistrationResponse.Java:

```
package dev.busboozted;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RegistrationResponse {

@SerializedName("result")
public String result;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult() { this.result = result;}

}
```

RegistrationBody.Java
    package dev.busboozted;

```
public class RegistrationBody {

public String login;
public String password;


public RegistrationBody(String login, String password)
{
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

Comment: У Вас сервер выдаёт в ответ лишнее, из-за этого Gson не может спарсить ответ в модель.

Comment: `onFailure` надо тоже в лог писать, чтобы иметь представление о ситуации, если что не так.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(res.result);
System.out.println("sdasdasdsadsad");
```

Явно не то, что вы хотите

Для вывода логов в Logcat используйте:

```
Log.d("TAG", res.result);
```

---

*P.S.подробнее про использование логов и их классификацию читайте в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)*

Comment: `System.out` тоже пишет в `LogCat` - суть проблемы не в этом

Comment: @woesss, да, пишет в логи, но только в *Information* (`Log.i`) и не на всех девайсах и эмуляторах

Comment: Тогда, наверное, стоит пояснить в ответе, почему не надо использовать `System.out` на Андроиде.